# Change starting index of list in python?

Tags: python, list

I made a program to find a prime number and store in list.
Now i want to print the exact position of the prime number
For eg. in the range of 2 to 20
If i take the input 6 it should print 13 not 17.

```
q=[]
for num in range(1,101):
    if num>1:
        if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(num**0.5+1))):
            q.append(num)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deduct `1` from the index:

```
print(q[6-1]) # -> 13
```

lists are zero-based so if you are going to use one-based indexing you need to simply subtract `1`, you should also maybe handle the case where a user enters `0`.

You can also start your range at 3 and use a step of 2 to get your primes:

```
q = [2]
for num in range(3, 101, 2):
    if num > 1:
        if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(3, int(num ** 0.5 + 1), 2)):
            q.append(num)
```

Comment: so what will you suggest for zero?

Comment: @YaShChaudhary, if you truly wanted to have a one-based array then an indexerror would be appropriate but it is completely dependant on what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 2):

```
q=[]
for num in range(1,101):
    if num>1:
        if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(num**0.5+1))):
             q.append(num)
index  = 6
print q[index-1]
```